# Vuejs pass input data from sub sub child component to parent

Tags: vue.js

How can i pass the value entered into `Name` and `Adres` input to the Parent vue?

Parent (App.vue):

```
<form-group-input-text
        :label="'test'"
        :labelvalue="'Name'"
        :inputplaceholder="'Name'"
        :inputname="'Name'"
        :inputvalue="''"
        :inputclassname="''"
        :inputid="'Name'"
        :validation="'required|min:3|max:5'">
</form-group-input-text>

<form-group-input-text
        :label="'testt'"
        :labelvalue="'Adres'"
        :inputplaceholder="'adres'"
        :inputname="'adres'"
        :inputvalue="''"
        :inputclassname="''"
        :inputid="'adres'"
        :validation="'required'">
</form-group-input-text>
```

Child:

```
<form-label
        :label="inputid"
        :labelvalue="labelvalue">
</form-label>

<form-error :inputname="inputname"></form-error>

<form-input-text
        v-on:input="handleTitle"
        :validation="validation"
        :inputplaceholder="inputplaceholder"
        :inputname="inputname"
        :inputvalue="inputvalue"
        :inputclassname="inputclassname"
        :inputid="inputid">
</form-input-text>
import Error from '../../form/validation/Error.vue'
import Label from '../../form/Label.vue'
import Input from '../../form/InputText.vue'

export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            inputvalue: ''
        }
    },
    components: {
        'form-label': Label,
        'form-input-text': Input,
        'form-error': Error
    },
    props: {
        label: String,
        labelvalue: String,
        inputplaceholder: String,
        inputname: String,
        inputclassname: String,
        inputid: String,
        validation: String
    },
    methods: {
        handleTitle: function (evt) {
            this.inputvalue = evt.target.value
        },
    }

}
```

Child from child:

```
<input type="text"
       v-on:input="updateValue($event)"
       v-validate="validation"
       :placeholder="inputplaceholder"
       :name="inputname"
       :value="inputvalue"
       :class="{
                    'form-control':'form-control',
                    'alert alert-danger': errors.has(inputname),
                    'alert alert-success': $validator.fields.find({ name: inputname })
                        && $validator.fields.find({ name: inputname }).flags.dirty
                        && !errors.has(inputname)
                }"
       :id="inputid"
>

<script>
    export default {
        inject: ['$validator'],
        props: {
            inputplaceholder: String,
            inputname: String,
            inputvalue: String,
            inputclassname: String,
            inputid: String,
            validation: String
        },
        methods: {
            updateValue: function (evt) {
                this.$emit('input', evt)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you keep propagating events?

Comment: What do you mean @zero298?

Comment: I mean what Hasu's answer is trying to pose.  Have the grandchild emit to the child and have the child emit to the grandparent.

Comment: See my updated code @zero298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way is to use `emit()` to dispatch an event to the parent component.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

You can use it with v-model, too https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Comment: You should showcase the solution rather than linking off to an external site. Links can change over time.

Comment: I have an emit from Child from child to Child

Comment: You can still propagate it up to the parent. 
Your code example is quite small, and we dont know what you do in your updateValue methods.

However you can v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" on boths inputs if you want to use v-model on the parent component.

Comment: @HasuKimchi See my aupdated code, how can i achieve this? Sorry i have two input fields

Comment: Have you tried just to emit the value again in your handleTitle method? It should actually work.

Comment: Do you mean that i have to emit again as i did in the child from child but now in the handleTitel method from Child?

Comment: If you want to emit from grandchild to grandparent it's best to use store:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Or you could implement an event bus:
https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/